# Showing a page to 1920x1080 monitors only, and another page to the rest of the monitor dimensions

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible, to show a main page (`index.html`) for `1920 x 1080` monitors and to show another **completely different** page (`product.html`) for monitors/phones/tablets/other electronics of different monitor dimensions? If possible, any examples?

Something like :-

```
if(screen = 1920x1080)
  // Show main page

else //if screen is not 1920x1080
  // Show a different page (different HTML and CSS)
```

Comment: Yes, that is possible.

Comment: Google "responsive css"

Comment: I see you have changed your question a little. The answer is for the tags that you have put this is **not** possible. Using JS or something like that then **yes**, that is possible.

Comment: Yeah, just updated the question (final change). And owh.. Javascript? Any notable examples?

Comment: @youdoreallysay There are a few ways you can do this. Check [**this little site**](http://www.coalmarch.com/blog/how-to-execute-javascript-based-on-screen-size-using-jquery), you can run Javascript function based on the window size. From here you could redirect the page to where you want to go or even load a page into an `iframe`. There will be more options then that so have a look around at the possibilities using JS.

Comment: You are ok with change in url for different devices.

Comment: @Ruddy, thanks for editing and clarifying my question, appreciate it :)

Comment: Check out [Media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries), and specifically for [different devices](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/).

Comment: @youdoreallysay Not a problem, if you create another question try to make it as clear as you can and include some sort of code that is relevant to your question (your attempt at the problem is always a good start).

Comment: On a sidenote, I don't believe that you would be unable to find an answer to your question after just 5 minutes of googling. Did you try to do some research before asking this question? [A similar question can be found here for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to do what you want with JS:

```html
if(window.innerWidth >= 1920 && window.innerHeight >= 1080){
  // Show main page
}else{//if screen is not 1920x1080
  // Show a different page (different HTML and CSS)
}
```

But, a better way is to do this in CSS with an @media query.

```css
@media (min-width: 300px) and (min-height: 200px) {
  /*CSS for main page*/
  .demo{
    background: gold;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 299px) and (max-height: 199px) {
  /*CSS for small page*/
  .demo{
    background: lightblue;
  }
}
.demo{
  padding: 10px;
  font: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<p class='demo'>
If your code snippet window is 300px wide or less and 200px high or less this text's background will be lightblue. Otherwise it will be gold. You can still write CSS outside the media queries, just they'll apply to the element regardless of any media queries.
</p>
```

Also, if you wanted to use the JS, you should use

```
window.location.assign('bar/foo.html')
```

That is, in the if/else for window.innerWidth/Height.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an javascript example. It redirects to the new page if the monitor is smaller than 1920x1080.  Include the code to the page for big screens (1920x1080).

```
if (window.innerHeight < 1080 && window.innerWidth < 1920) {
    window.location.href = 'path/to/new/page.html';
}
```

You could simply put the above code into `<script></script>` tags and put them in your the `<head></head>` section of your first page. So the code can execute before the DOM is ready.

EDIT: An other way would be to create an extra html page without conten, only with the below code inside it, which redirects to the wished site.

```
if (window.innerHeight < 1080 && window.innerWidth < 1920) {
    window.location.href = 'path/to/new/page.html';
} else {
    window.location.href = 'path/to/other/bigger/page.html';
}
```

Comment: Gotcha. Why isn't there an else statement? Is it because the code only states ONLY IF the screen dimension is 1920 x 1080?

Comment: Include the above code to the first page. For >1920x1080. The edit part would have an else.

Answer (score -1):

```
var source = 'html/htmlpage.cshtml';
if (screen.width >= 1920)
 source  = 'html/htmlpage1920.cshtml';
else if (screen.width <= 1024)
 source  = 'html/htmlpage1024.cshtml';
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = source;
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
head.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: The question has changed, this is incorrect. -1

Comment: @Ruddy . Now answer also changed. this will work

Comment: @Arjun, Thanks for your answer! How about the height?

Comment: same as width , using screen.height . so finally screen.width >1920 and   screen.height > 1000